# Time series in R in column

Tags: r, time, series

I do have time series with months in rows instead of columns. It's quite a large dataset and I am looking for a way to get the mean for every 12 rows, in this case for temperature so that a smaller dataset will emerge.

Comment: Please search SO for grouping data, otherwise create a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `group_by` and `summarize` from `dplyr`. First you have to create "groups", variable that will be used for grouping data.

```
library(dplyr)

dta <- data.frame(temp = rnorm(60, 0, 1))

dta$group <- sort(rep(1:12, 60/12))
dta %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(mean_temp = mean(temp))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   group mean_temp
   <int>     <dbl>
 1     1   -0.582 
 2     2    0.490 
 3     3   -0.197
```